# Rearrange a table in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datatable

I have a table (example_table.txt) with more than 700 of rows. Each row contains the value corresponding to 17 different classes. I want to rearrange my table in the following manner (Desired_output.text)

Example_table.txt link (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sz9XkPzMqCZItUBN-QugQKq39X0buIoX/view?usp=sharing)

Desired_output.txt link (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OXm2b4VMbuQ1GqBzBf48bDE_gPyzRpnU/view?usp=sharing)

Input table

```
ID  Class 1 Class 2 Class 3 Class 4 Class 5 Class 6 Class 7 Class 8 Class 9 Class 10    Class 11    Class 12    Class 13
1   0   0.0013865   0   0   0.0005675   0.00317325  0.00008725  0   0.0000925   0   0   0   0
2   0   0.02396475  0   0   0.00045075  0.008391    0.00161075  0   0.00033725  0   0   0   0
3   0   0.0260415   0   0   0   0.0210125   0.011682    0   0.00092125  0   0   0   0
4   0   0.01287525  0   0.00007425  0   0.02698525  0.02130875  0   0.0012565   0   0   0   0
5   0   0.008697    0.00012475  0   0.012641    0.00643825  0.0332455   0   0.00116475  0   0.00018875  0   0
```

Desired Output

```
Id  No of class and Class Name  Area
1   5   
    2   0.0013865
    5   0.0005675
    6   0.00317325
    7   0.00008725
    9   0.0000925
2   5   
    2   0.02396475
    5   0.00045075
    6   0.008391
    7   0.00161075
    9   0.00033725
3   4   
    2   0.0260415
    6   0.0210125
    7   0.011682
    9   0.00092125
4   5   
    2   0.01287525
    4   0.00007425
    6   0.02698525
    7   0.02130875
    9   0.0012565
5   7   
    2   0.008697
    3   0.00012475
    5   0.012641
    6   0.00643825
    7   0.0332455
    9   0.00116475
    11  0.00018875
```

How to rearrange this data in the desired manner using python

Comment: What is area in your output file?

Comment: data corresponding to a given class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas `df.melt`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\example_table.txt',delimiter='\t')
ExpectedOutput = df.melt(id_vars = 'ID',var_name='No of class and Class Name', value_name='Area')
ExpectedOutput = ExpectedOutput[ExpectedOutput.Area != 0] #remove record with 0 values
ExpectedOutput.sort_values(by=['ID'], inplace=True, ascending=True) #sort the data
ExpectedOutput['No of class and Class Name'] = ExpectedOutput['No of class and Class Name'].str.split(' ').str[1] #split and get class name from "class x" string


 ID No of class and Class Name  Area
1   5   0.000567
1   2   0.001386
1   7   0.000087
1   6   0.003173
1   9   0.000092
... ... ... ...
783 7   0.005627
783 4   0.000896
783 3   0.001235
783 2   0.045130
783 12  0.006651
```

Comment: yet drop those rows where area is equal to 0 and sort it by ID: `df.sort_values(by=['ID'], inplace=True, ascending=False)`, this should give desired output

Comment: Ahh. I didn't realize he was dropping the zero values in expected output. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

would duplicate the array with a ID and classes array:

```
classes = np.tile(np.arange(len(df.columns)),(df.shape[0],1)).flatten()
IDs = np.tile(df.index.values.reshape([-1,1]),(1,df.shape[1])).flatten()

X = df.values.flatten()
```

Dropping zero's

```
mask = X!=0


dfNew = pd.DataFrame()

dfNew['ID'] = IDs[mask]
dfNew['Classes'] = classes[mask]
dfNew['area'] = X[mask]
```

And then a groupby:
dfNew.groupby(['ID','Classes'])['area'].sum()

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to transform the data.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# copy data from original post into triple-quoted string
data='''ID   Class 1  Class 2  Class 3  Class 4  Class 5  Class 6  Class 7  Class 8  Class 9  Class 10     Class 11     Class 12     Class 13
1   0   0.0013865   0   0   0.0005675   0.00317325  0.00008725  0   0.0000925   0   0   0   0
2   0   0.02396475  0   0   0.00045075  0.008391    0.00161075  0   0.00033725  0   0   0   0
3   0   0.0260415   0   0   0   0.0210125   0.011682    0   0.00092125  0   0   0   0
4   0   0.01287525  0   0.00007425  0   0.02698525  0.02130875  0   0.0012565   0   0   0   0
5   0   0.008697    0.00012475  0   0.012641    0.00643825  0.0332455   0   0.00116475  0   0.00018875  0   0
'''
```

Now process the data in three steps:

```
# create data frame
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s\s+', engine='python', index_col='ID')

# convert 'Class n' to 'n' (with type integer)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Class ', '').astype(int).rename('class_num')

# re-shape, filter, sort, rename
df = df.stack().loc[lambda x: x > 0].sort_index().rename('area')

# UPDATE: count of IDs with non-zero area
t = df.groupby(level=0).transform('count').rename('non-zero-count')
df = pd.concat([df, t], axis=1)

# show first 10 rows
df.head(10)

                  area  non-zero-count
ID class_num                          
1  2          0.001386               5
   5          0.000567               5
   6          0.003173               5
   7          0.000087               5
   9          0.000092               5
2  2          0.023965               5
   5          0.000451               5
   6          0.008391               5
   7          0.001611               5
   9          0.000337               5
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this will help a lot,

I just want to add number of classes (having area more than zero) next to every ID

'1   5   
    2   0.0013865
    5   0.0005675
    6   0.00317325
    7   0.00008725
    9   0.0000925'

like 5 next to ID 1 is the number of classes having value more than zero

Thanks

Comment: I updated the code to count non-zero values of area (grouped by ID).  The new lines have `groupby` and `concat`.  You would be able to create the final output from this one data frame, IIUC.

Comment: I am unable to get result in the following manner [link] https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OXm2b4VMbuQ1GqBzBf48bDE_gPyzRpnU/view?usp=sharing